# select elements by attribute range with cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I wanted to select nodes with certain width range with cytoscape.js, but couldn't get it working.

In the [documentation](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/documentation/md/selectors.md) there is this example on selecting nodes of certain weight and height:

```
// get all nodes with weight more than 50 and height strictly less than 180
cy.elements("node[weight >= 50][height < 180]");
```

So far I have tried:

```
// 1
cy.elements("node[width < 200]");
// 2
cy.filter("node[width < 200]");
// 3
{
    selector:'node[width < 200]',
    css: {
        // do something
    }
}
```

but none of the above worked. Those just returned an empty collection of nodes. It worked fine when I removed the condition in []. What did I miss there?

PS: 
Eventually what I hope to achieve is that all nodes are of the same width, unless the text is too long. Right now I'm using auto width `'width':'label'` for all nodes and trying to adjust the small ones to the minimum width. Is there a better way of doing it?

Really appreciate it if someone can shed a light on this.

Comment: in the docs the given example makes filtering on "data" attributes of elements. You can get data attributes of an element with data() function. What you want is to query style attributes. These are very different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it in two different ways:

**Option A**:

```
cy.nodes().filter("node[width < 200]").filter(["node[height < 180]").style("your css property")
```

**Option B**:

```
cy.nodes().filter(function( element, i ){
  return element.data('width' < 200) && element.data('height' < 180)
}).style("your css property");
```

Comment: your answer selects elements by filtering "data" attributes and applies some style change. .style() function changes style of the elements